# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I want to multiply two variables.They are raw inputs but it always gives me that error.

```
no1 = raw_input('Your first number')
no2 = raw_input('Your second number')

answer = no1 * no2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, convert them to integers or floats first to perform numeric operations.

```
no1 = float(raw_input('Your first number'))
no2 = float(raw_input('Your second number'))
```

On py2.x you can also use `input` if which will automatically convert the input string to a 
number. But it's not safe if the source of input is not known.

help on `raw_input`:

```
>>> print raw_input.__doc__
raw_input([prompt]) -> string

Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

help on `input`:

```
>>> print input.__doc__
input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply 2 strings, so you need to convert them manually to floats by calling `float` function on `raw_input` result.

In python 2 you can also use `input` function instead of `raw_input` - it will do it automatically.

***WARNING*** - this function is completely insecure - it executes input string as python code (in the same way as `eval` function). Do not use it unless you trust the user